# How to search for MongoDB documents by name using an API GET endpoint?

Tags: json, mongodb, get, pymongo

I currently have a list of businesses in a MongoDB database (the data structure can be found below). I would like to create a REST API endpoint to search for documents by "name" instead of "_id".

```
[ 
  {  
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Apple",
    "reviews": [
      {
        "_id": "1",
        "comment": "Good",
      }
    ]
  },
  {  
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Microsoft",
    "reviews": [
      {
        "_id": "1",
        "comment": "Great",
      }
    ]     
  } 
]
```

Currently, I have a GET API endpoint that utilises the **find_one()** method where the user can supply the business _id field in the URL and retrieve that business. For example, if the user visits **http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/businesses/1**, Apple will be retrieved along with its reviews.

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/businesses/<string:id>", methods=["GET"])
def show_one_business(id): 
    business = businesses.find_one({'_id':ObjectId(id)})
    if business is not None:
        business['_id'] = str(business['_id'])
        for review in business['reviews']:
            review['_id'] = str(review['_id'])
        return make_response( jsonify ( [ business ] ), 200 )
    else:
        return make_response( jsonify( {"error" : "Invalid business ID"} ), 404 )
```

**How do I create an API endpoint to retrieve Apple by providing its name?** I assume it will be similar to the REST API above, but I attempted to change the '_id' values to 'name' values, but that didn't work.

Comment: use 
`  businesses.find_one({'name':name_to_query})  `

Comment: Hi Vim, thank you for the suggestion. Your code works in the MongoDB shell when I run teh command 'businesses.find_one ( { "name" : "Apple" } ), however, I'm struggling to apply it to my API above. I've a question; would I keep my current URL (/api/v1.0/businesses/<string:id>?